# iOS 8.3 SLComposeViewController Facebook bug

Tags: facebook, slcomposeviewcontroller

I have just noticed a problem in SLComposeViewController Facebook, no text is not to display inside, even official the Youtube application has this problem, do you have a solution?

Comment: This is an issue with iOS 8.3. A bug report has been submitted.

Comment: @victor Do you get any another solution for now?....m facing same issue

Comment: seeing this issue as well

Comment: I'm not getting URL to show up either...

Comment: if you are posting image, ensure you do not addURL because the URL will display instead of the image. Pretty stupid and damaging bugs.

Answer (score 8):

Facebook Officially admits Empty box is by design and they are working on Cancel/Done issue

```
https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/962985360399542/
```

Comment: It is strange of adding an Empty box is by design , then they expect people to type stuff?  Strange.

Comment: This should be considered the correct answer. The box is blank if you have the Facebook app installed, and populated with your text if you don't. The app is apparently replacing Apple's share sheet with its own deliberately-crippled version.